# Android Java Time Picker Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, timepicker

hey I am trying to make a TimepickerDialog. But the app crashes soon as I press the Set Time button. Here is the code.

MainActivity:

```
package com.wifitimer;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DateFormat formatDateTime=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
Calendar dateTime=Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void chooseTime(){
    new TimePickerDialog(this, t, dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        dateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        dateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    }
};
}
```

Am I missing some permissions or anything?

Here is the logcat as requested:

```
04-15 13:42:24.564: D/libEGL(31887): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-15 13:42:24.589: D/libEGL(31887): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-15 13:42:24.594: D/libEGL(31887): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-15 13:42:24.599: D/(31887): Device driver API match
04-15 13:42:24.599: D/(31887): Device driver API version: 10
04-15 13:42:24.599: D/(31887): User space API version: 10 
04-15 13:42:24.599: D/(31887): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
04-15 13:42:24.654: D/OpenGLRenderer(31887): Enabling debug mode 0
04-15 13:42:28.524: D/AndroidRuntime(31887): Shutting down VM
04-15 13:42:28.524: W/dalvikvm(31887): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416922a0)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method chooseTime(View) in the activity class com.wifitimer.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'timeBtn'
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3678)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: chooseTime [class android.view.View]
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3671)
04-15 13:42:28.544: E/AndroidRuntime(31887):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks

Comment: show your log generated by logcat?

Comment: what is the logcat output when it crash?

Comment: Logcat added to main post above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are calling chooseTime() from your xml layout file onClick attribute you need to change method signature to this

```
public void chooseTime(View view){

    new TimePickerDialog(this, t, dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();

}
```

Comment: Most probably the case. However, don't use listeners in XML. They're excruciatingly slow on anything before 2.3 (and 2.3 itself to some extent). In general, avoid anything that uses Reflection, since Dalvik is really bad at doing it efficiently.

Comment: I added the View view to the chooseTime() and removed the Listener() completely, By doing so I get a new error: "t" cannot be resolved to a variable. This error is with the new TimePickerDialog()

Answer (score 0):

change method like

```
public void chooseTime(View view){
    new TimePickerDialog(this, t, dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
}
```

and in You `xml Control` Like

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagestart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="chooseTime"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing `TimepickerDialog`, there's no need to add any type of permission.

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     Button b1;
     static final int TIME_OPENDIALOG_ID = 0;
     private int mHour,mMinute;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(TIME_OPENDIALOG_ID);
                updateDisplay();
            }

        });
    }
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mopenSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
    private Object pad(int mMinute2) {
        if (mMinute2 >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(mMinute2);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(mMinute2);
    }
    private void updateDisplay() {
        b1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(mMinute)));

    }
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_OPENDIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mopenSetListener, mHour, mMinute,
                    false);

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Time" />

</RelativeLayout>
```