# TimePickerDialog not showing, why?

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, android-timepicker

I want a TimePickerDialog to show instead of the keyboard, when the user clicks a button (the EditText field). I'm not getting any errors in Eclipse, but the dialog doesn't show.

...why?

XML:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/project_start_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="newStartTime" />
```

Code:

```
public void newStartTime ( View view ) {
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener newTime = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet ( TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute ) {
            // DO STUFF
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: I dont see any code launching a TimePickerDialog ...

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015381/android-java-time-picker-dialog to show time picker

Comment: Not getting it. How do I launch TimePickerDialog?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your xml it is an edit_text not a button. xml should be like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/project_start_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="newStartTime" />
```

Comment: Hmm, so I can't launch TimePickerDialog instead of keyboard from EditText?

Comment: In your thread you asked how to launch TimePickerDialog on a button click right?

Comment: No, how to launch it instead of the keyboard on clicking EditText.